# Is there a good wrapper for using Media Player in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-media-player

I need to add media playback ability to a web application. It has to play audio and video, and the player has to be MS Media Player (shouldn't use any plugin non existent on a standard windows machine). I know I can add it directly as an ActiveX to IE, and control it with JavaScript. I wonder if there is some popular and good wrapper that will save me some of the work.

UPADTE: Having a way to easily embed the player on the page is cool. But I would like the interaction with the player to be managed too. Things I would like it to support:

- Play
- Pause
- Stop
- Load different media clip
- Change volume
- resize

Also I would like to be able to replace the default controls (visible in the Windows Media Player) with my own skinned controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, this one should help:

http://malsup.com/jquery/media/

Comment: Here are some links: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms983653.aspx
http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/402377-how-to-control-Windows-Media-Player-or-Quicktime-embedded-in-a-web-page-from-Javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Flowplayer is also a good one:  http://flowplayer.org/

Comment: This is flash based. Nice. But I need only MS Media Player based solution